# Hot Reload works on iPhone simulator but not directly on iPhone

Tags: visual-studio, maui, hot-reload

I have a MAUI Visual Studio project connected to an Apple MacBook. If I use the iPhone simulator I can change my C# code and clicking on "Hot Reload" I can see the changes almost instantly, but when I connect directly to my iPhone device "Hot Reload" does not seem to do anything and the only way to see my changes is to re-deploy the entire application.

Am I missing something or is it just that Hot Reload does not work on this scenario?

Note: This is different to XAML Hot Reload, which works fine for me in both a physical iPhone and on the simulator.

Hot Reload: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/hot-reload

XAML Hot Reload: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/hot-reload

Comment: You select iOS Local Device > Alfort's Phone > Debug. Then, when a prompt is showed, to run the app from the phone, you click the icon on the phone. Right? For XAML it should work. For classes - not sure.

Comment: It is for "classes", for actual C# code, that it is not working, but it works on an iPhone simulator

Comment: I mean, it is prompting you that "restart is required" when you make changes. What do you make of that?

Comment: No, it's not telling me that. It is a code change that is allowed on Hot Reload and it works if I am using the iPhone simulator but on an physical iPhone it does not do anything when I click on "Hot Reload"

Answer (score 0):

.NET MAUI `XAML Hot Reload` is a Visual Studio feature that enables you to view the result of **XAML changes** in your running app, without having to rebuild your project.

Additionally, if you're debugging on a physical iPhone and your app becomes unresponsive, check that the `interpreter` is **enabled**. To enable the interpreter on iOS, you need add below to your project setting(csproj):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <UseInterpreter Condition="$(TargetFramework.EndsWith('-ios'))">true</UseInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I am not referring to XAML Hot Reload but to the "Hot Reload" button that allows some type of changes in actual code without having to redeploy. XAML Hot Reload works fine when using a physical iPhone

Comment: @Alfort Thanks for your response! I don't think it's supported for C# code for hot reload. As [the tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/hot-reload?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vswin) is for XAML not C# code.

Comment: It is that we are talking about different things. I refer to Hot Reload https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/hot-reload?view=vs-2022 not XAML Hot Reload

Comment: @Alfort It's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201). And also, you can search the Developer Community to see if there's an existing one that resembles the issue.

Comment: try to change the scheme of the build to release instead of debug

Comment: What's the type of the provision profile you're using? is it for development or for distribution ? for my application, i have 2 types of provision profiles, one for development which allows me to do the hot reload on the actual IOS device and the distribution one which allows me to deploy with out debugging nor hot reload.